# Median of Medians in 2D Array/Matrix

Tags: matrices, matlab, median

This is a bit of a mathematics problem, and a MATLAB problem.

In MATLAB, if I call `median(M)`, where `M` is an `m x n` 2D matrix, I get a list of `n` values which represent the median value for each of the `n` columns.

I'm trying to derive a proof (for my own curiosity) for:

- Let `W` be a `1 x n` vector that corresponds to the median values for each column in the `m x n` matrix, `M`
- Let `W = median(M)`
- Prove whether or not whether the median of `W` is always equal to the median value of all values of `M`

  - In MATLAB parlance, this would be akin to, "is `median(median(M))` the true median of `M` if `M` were normalized to a `1 x (nm)` vector, `V`, and we calculated `median(V)`.

Is there an existing proof or general rule that dictates whether or not the median of a set of data is equal to the median of medians of any arbitrary subsets?  Due to linearity, I can assume this to be true for the average (ie: arithmetic mean), but I'm not so sure about the mode and median operations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same. To prove it, a counterexample suffices. There are two cases:

- Even number of rows/columns: Matlab's definition of median implies an interpolation between the two central values.

  ```
  >> median(median([1 2; 3 40]))
  ans =
     11.5000

  >> median([1 2 3 40])
  ans =
     2.5000
  ```
- Odd number of rows/columns: no interpolation needed; the median is just the central value:

  ```
  >> median(median([1 2 30; 4 5 60; 10 20 30]))
  ans =
       5

  >> median([1 2 30 4 5 60 10 20 30])
  ans =
      10
  ```

Comment: Thank you sir.  On a side note, is it possible to disable the interpolation thing MATLAB does? That sounds like an incredibly stupid feature to use as a default.

Comment: @Dogbert No, I don't think it can be disabled. I agree that defining the median like that is stretching things a bit. But on the other hand, how would you define the median of `x = [1 3 4 2]`? To me, taking `2.5` as the result does make some sense. Anyway, if you want to define it differently you could do `y = sort(x)` and then choose `y(floor(numel(y)/2))` or whatever you want to use

Comment: I still prefer your approach. So long as there is a strict rule known in advance, it seems far preferable to the median potentially being a value not in the original set `M`.